# Can't figure out why do I keep getting an error opening a file in C

Tags: c, file

I have to write a program, wchich opens a file in binary mode and calculates the size of it. I have to write only one function to do that and it only has to have one parameter, which is the name of the data file.

I insert the name of the file and keep getting the error message and I can't figure out why.

Here's the function

```
long getFileSize (char * fileName) {

    long size_Of_File = 0;
    FILE *data_file;
    data_file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if (data_file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening the file!\n");
            return -1;
    };

    fseek(data_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_Of_File = ftell(data_file);

    fclose(data_file);
    return size_Of_File;
}
```

and the function main() if you need it:

```
int main () {
    char * fileName;
    fileName = (char *) malloc (50 * sizeof(char));  //maximum length of the filename is 50 symbols
    long file_size;


    if (fileName != NULL) {
        printf ("Please write the name of the data file (with \'.txt\' prefix): ");
        fgets(fileName, 50, stdin);
        file_size = getFileSize(fileName);
        printf ("The size of the file is %li bytes.\n", file_size);
    } else {
        printf ("Could not allocate memory!\n");
    };

   free(fileName);
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: First of all, ".txt" is a suffix, not a prefix. Do you provide the filename including its path? Otherwise the work directory is given. Are you running on windows?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to remove the trailing newline from `fileName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Karzes mentioned, you will need to remove the newline byte from the array of characters.

A simple way you could do this is to step through the array of characters one byte at a time, checking to see if the current byte is the newline character and replacing it with the string terminator byte '\0'.

```
//...

fgets(fileName, 50, stdin);

//Replace the first occurrence of \n with \0 to end the string.
for ( int i=0; i<50; i++ ) {
  if ( fileName[i] == '\n' ) {
    fileName[i] = '\0';
    break;
  }
}

//...
```